# Flutter exception on debounce method with Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, debouncing

I call a debounce method when i use onChanged in order to reduce the number of call to the API.
Actually, if i'm on the page, i tape something in the searchbar, i get results, i can go back without errors.
But if i'm on the page, and i press go back button, i get this error :

```
The following _CastError was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      Debounce.dispose
package:drawer/…/share/debounce.dart:17  -> void dispose() => _timer!.cancel();
#1      _HistoriquePageState.dispose
package:drawer/…/pages/historique_page.dart:26 -> _debounce.dispose();
```

This is my code :

```
class _HistoriquePageState extends State<HistoriquePage> {
  final _debounce = Debounce();
  DateTimeRange? dateRange;
  String searchedValue = "";
  Post? user;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _debounce.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _sendSearch(String value) {
    _debounce.run(() {
      setState(() {
        searchedValue = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
......
......
onChanged: _sendSearch
...
...
```

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Debounce {
  final int milliseconds;
  late VoidCallback action;
  Timer? _timer;

  Debounce({this.milliseconds = 500});

  void run(VoidCallback action) {
    if (_timer?.isActive != null) _timer!.cancel();
    _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: this.milliseconds), action);
  }

  void dispose() => _timer!.cancel();
}
```

So as i said, the problem occurs ONLY if i don't tape something to throw _sendSearch and i press go back.
If i tape something, and i go back no error.

Flutter version : 2.2.0